# How to utilize useEffect hooks to fetch data from Firebase RealTime Database

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, firebase-realtime-database, react-hooks, use-effect

I have an issue where when my user is a new user both my create profile and create characters to FireBase Realtime database are not loading before my user profile page renders.  I understand that useEffects run after the render.  But after user profile and characters are created in the database I don't have the issue.  I can log off and refresh my app, sign in and everything loads in time.  Here is m code.  I've tried writing my functions inside the useEffect several different ways and I get the same results every time.  I saw one post where someone using a .then() but that doesn't appear to work in my situation.  I rather not use any additional add-ins like AXIOs or other packages.  I feel like there has to be a way to do this with the native built in tools of React and Firebase.  Any advice is much appreciated. Edit: Here is my layout.
App.js

```
            <AuthProvider>
              <DBProvider>
                <Switch>
                  <PrivateRoute path="/profile" component={ProfileBar} />
                  <PrivateRoute path="/update-profile" component={UpdateProfile} />
                  <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
                  <Route path="/signup" component={Signup} />
                  <Route path="/forgot-password" component={ForgotPassword} />
                </Switch>
              </DBProvider>
            </AuthProvider>
          </Router>
```

AuthContext.js

```
import React, { useContext, useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import { auth} from '../firebase'

const AuthContext = React.createContext()


export function useAuth() {
    return useContext(AuthContext)
}

export function AuthProvider({ children }) {
    const [currentUser, setCurrentUser] = useState()
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true)
  

    function signup(email, password, displayName) {

    let promise = new Promise ((resolve, reject) => {
            auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
            .then((ref) => {
                ref.user.updateProfile({
                    displayName: displayName
                });
                resolve(ref);
            })
            .catch((error) => reject(error));
        })
        return promise
    }

 useEffect(() => {
      const unsubscribe = auth.onAuthStateChanged(user => {
            setCurrentUser(user)
            setLoading(false)
        })
      
        return unsubscribe
    }, [])

}
```

DBContext.js

```
import { db } from '../firebase'
import { useAuth } from './AuthContext'
import React, { useState, useEffect, useContext } from 'react'

const DBContext = React.createContext()  // React Database FireStore .DB

export function useDB() {
 useContext(DBContext);
}

export function DBProvider({ children }) {
    const [profileData, setProfileData] = useState()
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true)
    const { currentUser } = useAuth()
   
   function checkCurrentUser(){
        if(currentUser){
            checkProfile()
        }
        if(!currentUser){
            setLoading(false)
            console.log("No current user logged in.")
        }
    }

    function checkProfile(){
        db.ref(`users/` + currentUser.uid + `/profile`)
        .on('value', (snapshot) => {
            const data = snapshot.val()
            if(data == null){
                console.log(data, "New user... Generating profile!")
                createUserProfile()
            } 
            if(data){
                getProfile()
            } 
        });
    }

    function createUserProfile(){

        let profile = {}
        profile.gameMaster = false
        profile.editor = false
        profile.email = currentUser.email
        profile.displayName = currentUser.displayName

        db.ref('users/' + currentUser.uid).set({
            profile
        }).then(() =>{
            getProfile()
        }) 

    }

    function getProfile(){
        db.ref(`users/` + currentUser.uid + `/profile`)
        .on('value', (snapshot) => {
            const profile = snapshot.val()
            setLoading(false)
            setProfileData(profile)
            console.log("Profile set to State from Database.")
        })
     }

    useEffect(() => {
     
      checkCurrentUser()
       
    },[])

}
```

Profile.js

```
    
      <Switch>
           <CharacterProvider>
                <Route path={`${match.path}/characters`} component={CharacterSheets} /> 
                 <Route path={`${match.path}/journal`} component={Journal} />
                 <Route path={`${match.path}/game_charts`} component={GameCharts} />
                  <Route path={`${match.path}/game_rules`} component={GameRules} />
            </CharacterProvider> 
       </Switch>
```

CharacterContext.js

```
   useEffect(() => {

        const ref = db.ref(`users/` + currentUser.uid + `/characters`)
       
            ref.on('value', snapshot => {
                    const data = snapshot.val()
                    if(data){

                        console.log("Setting Characters to State from Database.")
                        setCharacters(JSON.parse(data))
                        setLoading(false)
       
                    }
                    if(data == null){

                        console.log("Setting Characters to State from template.")
                        setCharacters(characterTemplate)
                        setLoading(false)
        
                    } 
                })
        
            return () => ref.off();
         
    }, [])


    useEffect(() => {
                 
        if(characters){
           db.ref(`users/` + currentUser.uid).child("/characters").set(JSON.stringify(characters)) 
        }
    
        console.log("Data saved to firebase.")
    
    }, [characters])
```

CharacterCards.js

```
import { useCharacter } from '../../../contexts/CharacterContext'
import CharacterCard from './CharacterCard'
import CharacterCardEdit from '../../ProfileContainer/CharacterEdit/CharacterCardEdit'
import SuccessRoller from '../CharacterComponents/SuccessRoller/SuccessRoller'

export default function CharacterCards() {
    const { handleCharacterAdd,  characters, selectedCharacter, selectedCharacterSuccessRoller } = useCharacter()
 
    return (
        <div>
            <div className="add_button-container">
                <button onClick={handleCharacterAdd} className="add_button-main" >Add Character</button>
            </div>
            <div className="parent-container">
                <div>
                    {characters?.map(character => {
                            return (
                                <CharacterCard key={character.id} {...character} />    
                            )
                        })
                    }
                </div>
                <div>
                    {selectedCharacter && <CharacterCardEdit character={selectedCharacter} />}
                    {selectedCharacterSuccessRoller && <SuccessRoller character={selectedCharacterSuccessRoller} />} 
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: I read your question now several times over and I still don't understand what exactly is your issue. Maybe I'm just especially dense today. Could you please try to clarify what your expected behavior is.

Comment: Please provide the code you are using to sign in and create your character data. In particular where `currentUser` is coming from.

Comment: @Martin: The expected behavior is when a new user "Sign Up" to the site my AuthContext.js will create the user in Firebase, then my DBContext.js will create a profile based on "user" data in the RealTime Database, then in my nested Routes CharacterContext.js will create a character in the RealTime Database under the same Profile.  It works.. but it doesn't load on the page only the first time a user signs in.  If I click on a different route like the Journal or Game Rules; the characters show up when I click back.  I apologize for my inexperience with posting questions.

Comment: @samthecodingman: I added my basic app layout.  I tried to only post the code that is being utilize during new user Sign Up.  Thanks.

Comment: With a quick look on the way to work, seems the `useEffect` on `DBcontext` isn't configured to rerun when `currentUser` changes. If you are still stuck in about 10 hours, I'll post a complete answer.

Comment: @samthecodingman: I added currentUser as a dependency in my DBContext useEffect and it didn't make a difference.  What is confusing is that the my currentUser.email will show up first time logging in.  Just the currentUser.displayName and my characters from the CharacterContext.js do not render unless I move to a different route in the nested router/switch.  I tried async await functions and that didn't make a difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your code is sharded out into many functions for readability, there are a lot of listeners that are created but don't get cleaned up. In particular great care needs to be taken with `.on` listeners as they may be re-fired (you could use `.once()` to help with this). An example of this bug is in `checkProfile()` which listens to the user's profile, then calls `getProfile()` which also listens to the profile. Each time the profile is added, another call to `getProfile()` is made, adding yet another listener. Plus, each of the listeners in `checkProfile()` and `getProfile()` aren't ever cleaned up.

I've made a number of assumptions about your code structure and untangled it so you can read and understand it top-to-bottom. This is especially important when working with React hooks as their order matters.

```
// firebase.js
import firebase from "firebase/app";
import "firebase/auth";
import "firebase/database";

firebase.initializeApp({ /* ... */ });

const auth = firebase.auth();
const db = firebase.database();

export {
  firebase,
  auth,
  db
}
```

```
// AuthContext.js
import { auth } from "./firebase";
import React, { useContext, useEffect, useState } from "react";

const AuthContext = React.createContext();

export default AuthContext;

export function useAuth() { // <- this is an assumption
  return useContext(AuthContext);
}

async function signup(email, password, avatarName) {
  const userCredential = await auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
  await userCredential.user.updateProfile({
    displayName: avatarName
  });
  return userCredential;
}

export function AuthProvider(props) {
  const [currentUser, setCurrentUser] = useState();
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => auth.onAuthStateChanged(user => {
    setCurrentUser(user)
    setLoading(false)
  }), []);
  
  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider
      value={{
        currentUser,
        loading,
        signup
      }}
    >
      {props.children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

```
// DBContext.js
import { db } from "./firebase";
import { useAuth } from "./AuthContext";
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const DBContext = React.createContext();

export default DBContext;

export function DBProvider(props) {
  const [profileData, setProfileData] = useState();
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const { currentUser, loading: loadingUser } = useAuth();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (loadingUser) {
      return; // still initializing, do nothing.
    }
    
    if (currentUser === null) {
      // no user signed in!
      setProfileData(null);
      return;
    }
    
    // user is logged in
    const profileRef = db.ref(`users/` + currentUser.uid + `/profile`);
    
    const listener = profileRef.on('value', snapshot => {
      if (!snapshot.exists()) {
        // didn't find a profile for this user
        snapshot.ref
          .set({ // <- this will refire this listener (if successful) with the below data
            gameMaster: false,
            editor: false,
            email: currentUser.email,
            displayName: currentUser.displayName
          })
          .catch((error) => console.error("Failed to initialize default profile", error));
        return;
      }
      
      setProfileData(snapshot.val());
      setLoading(false);
    });
    
    return () => profileRef.off('value', listener); // <- cleans up listener
  }, [currentUser, loadingUser]);
  
  return (
    <DBContext.Provider
      value={{
        profileData,
        loading
      }}
    >
      {props.children}
    </DBContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

```
// CharacterContext.js
import { db } from "./firebase";
import { useAuth } from "./AuthContext";
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const CharacterContext = React.createContext();

export default CharacterContext;

export function CharacterProvider(props) {
  const { currentUser, loading: loadingUser } = useAuth();
  const [characters, setCharacters] = useState();
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
   
  useEffect(() => {
    if (loadingUser) {
      return; // still initializing, do nothing.
    }

    if (!currentUser) {
      // no user signed in!
      setCharacters(null);
      return;
    }

    const charactersRef = db.ref(`users/${currentUser.uid}/characters`);
   
    const listener = charactersRef.on('value', snapshot => {
      if (!snapshot.exists()) {
        // no character data found, create from template
        snapshot.ref
          .set(DEFAULT_CHARACTERS); // <- this will refire this listener (if successful)
          .catch((error) => console.error("Failed to initialize default characters", error));
        return;
      }
      
      setCharacters(JSON.parse(snapshot.val()));
      setLoading(false);
    });
    
    return () => charactersRef.off('value', listener);
  }, [currentUser, loadingUser]);
  
  return (
    <CharacterContext.Provider
      value={{
        characters,
        loading
      }}
    >
      {props.children}
    </CharacterContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

Comment: This is fantastic.  I am still a beginner coder and in my quest to resolve my issue I can see that I got lost with testing different code.  I had used the .once() method and return ref.off() in my useEffects with no luck.  But I think your addition of loading: loadingUser is what I was missing.  I'll update once i've adding the changes.  :D

Comment: I updated my code with the exception of using props in my export functions "providers".  I keep the { children } in both DB and Character Context.  The changes to the DBContext.js worked for displaying both the email and displayName during profile.js render.  However in the Realtime database the displayName didn't generate under profile.  I deleted the profile object from the DB while logged in and it automatically recreated with the displayName.  And Characters still didn't load.  So I added my CharacterCards.js to show how I map characters.  Thanks for all. your help.

Comment: I updated my post with your suggestions.  So you can see what I may have missed.

Comment: You really shouldn't edit your question with an answers code. The question should remain the same but you can add information to it like `CharacterCards.js` in it's current form. You've also readded a `useEffect` I removed in `CharacterContext.js` that was causing an infinite loop. When you add/remove characters, you should modify the database directly and let the useEffect handle updating `characters` for you.

Comment: I apologize for updating the post. I can restore it back to the original post.  Without that second useEffect my database doesn't update when I edit my characters.  It only appears to update the database with every change.  I feel like your answer has pointed me on the right path to solving my issue.  I appreciate all the advice @samthecodingman.

Comment: I figured out what you meant by updating the database directly.  I removed the second useEffect and added my update character code in my handleCharacterChange() function.  Thanks again you're advice is helping me resolve many issues.