# Using the context API in react/typescript with firebase

Tags: reactjs, typescript, firebase, react-context

I am new to typescript, and so I am having trouble incorporating it into the context API. I am running into a number of problems, and when I fix one, it causes another.

```
// AuthContext.tsx

interface User {
  email: string;
  password: string;
}

const defaultValue: User = {
  email: "",
  password: "",
};

const AuthContext = createContext(defaultValue);

type AuthProviderProps = {
  children: ReactNode;
};

const AuthProvider = ({ children }: AuthProviderProps) => {
  const [user, setUser] = useState();

  const signUpHandler = (email: string, password: string) => {
    return createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
      setUser(user);
    });

    return unsubscribe;
  }, []);

  const value = {
    user,
    signUpHandler,
  };

  return <AuthContext.Provider value={value}>{children}</AuthContext.Provider>;
};

export default AuthProvider;

export const useAuth = () => {
  return useContext(AuthContext);
};
```

1. I get an error for `setUser(user)` saying: `Argument of type 'User | null' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<undefined>'.`
2. value:{value} shows me an error saying:

   `Type '{ user: undefined; signUpHandler: (email: string, password: string) => Promise<UserCredential>; }' is missing the following properties from type 'User': email, passwordts(2739) index.d.ts(371, 9): The expected type comes from property 'value' which is declared here on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & ProviderProps<User>'`

Shouldn't the missing `email` and `password` be found on the `user` state?

3. When I try and use `signUpHandler` in `SignUp.tsx` it shows me an error saying: `Property 'signUpHandler' does not exist on type 'User'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ultimately, your problems stem from the inherited types that are derived from certain lines in your code.

For the first problem, this line calls `useState` without an initial value and/or type:

```js
const [user, setUser] = useState();
```

This means that `user` gets defined with the type of `undefined` and `setUser` is defined as `SetStateAction<undefined>`.

To make it so that `user` is `User | null` to match the callback of `onAuthStateChanged(user => { /* ... */ })`, you need to specify the type (and you should set the default value) in the `useState` call:

```js
const [user, setUser] = useState<User | null>(null);
```

For the latter problems, it is caused by these lines:

```js
const defaultValue: User = {
  email: "",
  password: "",
};

const AuthContext = createContext(defaultValue);
```

In these lines, you define your AuthContext as a `React.Context<User>` object. This means that your `value` object for your context should also be a `User` object, but you instead try to provide an object with the following shape:

```js
{
  user: User | null; // after fixing the first problem line
  signUpHandler: (email: string, password: string) => Promise<UserCredential>;
}
```

You need to make sure that this `value` object and the `defaultValue` object have the same shape. To make this easier, you also want to lift your `signupHandler` method outside of the component as it will not be changing between renders.

```
// top of AuthContext.tsx

// stateless static helper methods go here
const signUpHandler = (email: string, password: string) => {
  return createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password);
};

type AuthContextData = {
  user: User | null;
  signUpHandler: typeof signUpHandler; // copies type from method itself
  ... // other methods/properties
}

const AuthContext = createContext<AuthContextData>({
  user,
  signUpHandler,
  ... // default values for other methods/properties
});
```

```
// inside AuthProvider component of AuthContext.tsx

const [user, setUser] = useState<User | null>(null);

/* other code */

const value: AuthContextData = {
  user,
  signUpHandler
}

return (
  <AuthContext.Provider value={value}>
    {children}
  </AuthContext.Provider>
);
```

These other threads have more examples: [Extending contexts](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67338385/3068190), [Complexly typed contexts](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68871889/3068190)

Comment: Thanks!! This makes a lot more sense.